# Считать число, имя, фамилию, отчество из файла в Си

Tags: c, строки, память, списки

Здравствуйте, создаю базу данных, содержащую информацию о студентах. Мне необходимо считать в 4 переменные число (номер группы) , фамилию, имя и отчество и запихнуть их в список, как считать правильно? Возможно через что-то вроде fgetc() и отслеживать пробелы?

Данные в файле представлены таким образом:

**6305 Chub Maria Petrovna**

**6306 Loganov Artem Petrovich**

Вот написал код, но конечно не работает:

```
student_base* CopyDataFile(student_base* head) {
    FILE* student_data;
    student_base* tmp;

    int num_group;
    char* name;
    char* surname;
    char* patronymic;

    //Открытие файла
    if (!fopen_s(&student_data,"student_data.txt", "r")) {
        while (fscanf_s(student_data, "%d %s %s %s", &num_group, surname, name, patronymic) == 4) {
            tmp = (student_base*)malloc(sizeof(student_base));
            tmp->num_group = num_group;
            tmp->surname = surname;
            tmp->name = name;
            tmp->patronymic = patronymic;
            head = PushEnd(head, tmp);
        }
    }
    else {
        fopen_s(&student_data, "student_data.txt", "w");
        fprintf(student_data, "Empty");
    }

    //Выведем на консоль, если чтение было успешным
    student_base* current = head;
    while (current) {
        printf("%d %s %s %s\n", current->num_group, current->surname, current->name, current->patronymic);
        current = current->next;
    }
    system("pause");
    return head;
}
```

P.S Функция PushEnd добавляет элемент в конец списка.

Comment: добавьте пожалуйста функцию добавления данных, а так же есть ли какие-либо ограничения на размер фамилии, имени, отчества?

Comment: Что за функция добавления данных? Ограничение на размер фамилии, имени , отчества нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут возможны 2 варианта решения, 1 с использованием пробелов, 2 более логичный, с использование "ограниченной в памяти" структуры.

1. Так как написан у вас scanf - нельзя, либо используете регулярные выражения, либо же ограниченные в памяти массивы(статические). В тоже время, вы можете просто считать  в один буфер весь файл и далее методом нахождения пробелов получить данные :

   ```
   student_base* CopyDataFile(char* filename, student_base* head)
   {
   FILE* data;
   student_base curr = head, temp = NULL;
   if (curr == NULL)
       curr = (student_base*)malloc(sizeof(student_base));

   while (curr->next!=NULL) 
       curr = curr->NULL;

   long lSize;
   char * buffer;
   size_t result;

   data = fopen ( "myfile.txt" , "rb" );
   if (data==NULL)
   {
       // обработать ошибку
   }

   fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
   lSize = ftell (pFile);
   rewind (pFile);

   buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize);
   if (buffer == NULL) 
   {
       //обработать ошибку
   }

   // copy the file into the buffer:
   result = fread ( buffer, 1, lSize, data);
   if (result != lSize) 
   {
       //обработать ошибку
   }
   //ну а сюда вставляете while, который будет идти до первого пробела
   //считывать строку и в зависимости от порядка трансформироваться в int 
   //либо же записываться в одно из строковых полей (ися, фамилия ...)
   fclose (data);
   return 0;
   }
   ```

Это первый вариант, рекоммендовал бы посмотреть документацию по [fread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/), [fseek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) и т.д.

2. А вот и второй способ

   ```
   //описание структуры
   //я рекомендую использовать чётко выделенный размер памяти под структуру
   //в данном случае 100 байтов
   typedef struct student{
   char[32] name;
   char[32] surname;
   char[32] patronymic;
   int group_num;
   } student;

   typedef struct student_base {
   student data;
   struct student_base next;
   } student_base;

   //head в моём понимании - указатель на первый элемент списка
   student_base* CopyDataFile(char* filename, student_base* head){
   FILE* data;
   student_base curr = head, temp = NULL;
   if (curr == NULL)
       curr = (student_base*)malloc(sizeof(student_base));

   while (curr->next!=NULL) 
       curr = curr->NULL;

   data=fopen("c:\\test.bin", "rb");
   if (data==NULL)
   {
       // обработать ошибку
   }   
   fseek(data, 0, SEEK_END);//установить указатель в конец
   int end_of_file = ftell(data);//считать позицию

   fseek(data, 0, SEEK_SET);//установить  в начало
   while ( ftell(pFile)!= end_of_file ){
       curr->next = (student_base*)malloc(sizeof(student_base));
       fread(curr->data, sizeof(student), 1, data);
       curr->next = NULL;
   }

   fclose(data);
   }
   ```

Коды я не тестировал, если будут какие-либо мелкие баги, пишите